# Why is the updated state variable not shown in the browser console?

Tags: reactjs

I understand that the method returned by useState is asynchronous, however, when I run the this code, I am delaying the console.log by upto 5 seconds, but it still logs the previous value and not the updated value of the state variable. The updated value would be 2, but it still logs 1. In the react developer tools however,  I can see the state changing as I press the button, though I am curious to know why after even such a delay the console prints an obsolete value? This is not the case with class components and setState but with function components and useState.

```
import "./App.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [variable, setVariable] = useState(1);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setVariable(2);
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(variable);
    }, 2000);
  };

  return <button onClick={handleClick}>Button</button>;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I would strongly advise agains relying on timers for state updates. In my opinion it's better to use class-based components with `setState`, in which you can use callbacks for when the state is done updating. This is a limitation with React hooks, and the very reason I never use them.

Comment: Here you have `setTimeout` inside `handleClick` function where you also set the state, so here `console.log(variable)` still holds the old value and the timer is attached to the browser and once the timer is resolved, it will get back you the value you logged in the time mentioned. The state won't update even you have `setTimeout`, it still remember the old value. Sameway if you move the `setTimeout` outside the handle click you will get the updated result.

Comment: @ManirajMurugan I'm not sure what you're trying to point out, but the state update and the setTimeout happen in the same function.

Comment: @paddotk, I agree both are in the same function but that doesn't mean it will update the state and provide the updated value to the `console.log(variable)` inside the `setTimeout` . That is not how it works. Here `setTimeout` just attaches the timer and wait for that time and inside that it holds `variable` as old value alone in memory and hence the value for `variable` still holds `1` and return you it once timer is resolved even though you update the state.

Comment: Why would it hold the old value in memory? This is determined at the moment of the execution of the function in `setTimeout`. It doesn't check that up front.

Answer (score 1):

In your code your `setTimeout` is getting the `variable` value from the closure at the time it was invoked and the callback function to the `setTimeout` was created. Check [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14010) for the detailed explanation.

In the same issue, they talk about utilizing `useRef` to do what you are attempting. [This article](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/) by Dan Abramov packages this into a convenient `useInterval` hook.

Answer (score 0):

A state take some time to update. The proper way to log state when it updates, is to use the `useEffect` hook.
`setTimeout` attaches the timer and wait for that time, but it will keep the value of `variable` from the beginning of the timer, witch is `1`

```
import "./App.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [variable, setVariable] = useState(1);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setVariable(2);
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(variable);
  }, [variable]);


  return <button onClick={handleClick}>Button</button>;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: If variable === 0 won't log despite being a valid count

Comment: Yeah, just an old reflex to not log unnecessary stuff. On the first render, if you set the variable to `null` or `undefined` you might not want to log it. I'm modifying the answer in this case

Answer (score 0):

State updates are asynchronous. That means, that in order to view the new value, you need to log It on the next render using `useEffect` and adding it to the dependencies array:

In this example, give a look at the order the logs appear:
First, you will have the current one, and once triggered, you will have the new value, and then it will become the 'old value' until triggered again.

```
import "./App.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => { console.log(`new state rolled: ${counter}`);
  }, [counter]);

  console.log(`Before rolling new State value: ${counter}`); 
  const handleClick = () => setCounter(counter++)
  
  return <button onClick={handleClick}>Button</button>;
}

export default App;
```

Another technic to console.log a value afterward a state change is to attach a callback to the setState:

```
setCounter(counter++, ()=> console.log(counter));
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

> This is not the case with class components and setState but with
> function components and useState

In class components, React keep the state in `this.state` & then call the `Component.render()` method whenever its need to update due to a `setState` or `prop` change.

Its something like this,

```
// pseudocode ( Somewhere in React code )

const app = MyClassComponent();
app.render();

// user invoke a callback which trigger a setState,
app.setState(10);

// Then React will replace & call render(),
this.state = 10;
app.render();
```

Even though you cannot do `this.state = 'whatever new value'`, React does that internally with class components to save the latest state value. Then react can call the `render()` method and render method will receive the latest state value from `this.state`

So, if you use a `setTimeout` in a class component,

```
setTimeout(() => {
 console.log(this.state) // this render the latest value because React replace the value of `this.state` with latest one
}, 2000)
```

---

However in functional component, the behaviour is little bit different, Every time when component need to re render, React will call the component again, And you can think the functional components are like the `render()` method of class components.

```
// pseudocode ( Somewhere in React code )

// initial render
const app = MyFuctionalComponent(); 

// state update trigger and need to update. React will call your component again to build the new element tree.
const app2 = MyFunctionalComponent();
```

The `variable` value in `app` is `1` & `variable` value in `app2` is `2`.

Note: `variable` is just a classic variable which returned by a function that hooked to the component ( The value save to the `variable` is the value return by the hook when the component was rendering so it is not like `this.state` i.e its hold the value which was there when the component is rendering but not the latest value )

Therefore according to the Clouser, at the time your `setTimeout` callback invoke ( Which was called from `app` ) it should log `1`.

---

How you can log the latest value ?

you can use `useEffect` which getting invoke once a render phase of a component is finished. Since the render phase is completed ( that mean the local state variables holds the new state values ) & `variable` changed your console log will log the current value.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(variable);
}, [variable])
```

If you need the behaviour you have in class components, you can try `useRef` hook. useRef is an object which holds the latest value just like `this.state` but notice that updating the value of `useRef` doesn't trigger a state update.

```
  const ref = useRef(0);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setVariable(2); // still need to setVariable to trigger state update
    ref.current = 2 // track the latest state value in ref as well.
    
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(ref.current); // you will log the latest value
    }, 2000);
  };
```